# Excel Countifs and Sumproduct

Tags: excel-formula

Using an excel function, I'd like to get a total count for "WO", "Satisfactory Performance" and anything in October from the following data set.  My expected total should be 1.

```
Region  Performance Rating       Date
WO      Satisfactory Performance    10/1/2018
01      Satisfactory Performance    10/18/2018
WO      Satisfactory Performance    11/16/2018
```

I've tried the following formula returning a value of 0, but it should be 1:

```
=COUNTIFS(Q103:Q105,"WO",R103:R105,"Satisfactory Performance",S103:S105,+SUMPRODUCT(1*(S103:S105)=10))
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what `+SUMPRODUCT(1*(S103:S105)=10)` is intended to accomplish. Typically you would simply bracket the month with COUNTIFS.

```
=COUNTIFS(Q103:Q105, "WO",
          R103:R105, "Satisfactory Performance",
          S103:S105, ">="&date(2018, 10, 1),
          S103:S105, "<"&date(2018, 11, 1),)
```

Comment: Why did you include the additional S103:S105, "<"&date(2018, 11, 1)?  Isn't this saying to include Nov in the count too?

Comment: no. the date conditions are *greater than or equal to 01-oct-2018 and less than 01-nov-2018*.

Comment: Thanks.  My miss - that makes sense.  That's what 16 hours of looking at numbers will do to someone.